# Xamarin Picker -- Opened List Display at Selected Index

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Good morning everyone. I have a picker which has already been selected to a value in the list. When the user re-opens the picker I would like the picker's list to start off at this selected index instead of at the beginning of the list. Is there any way to do this?

As shown here the picker is set to water.

[image]

However if the user opens the picker it starts off at Letter A. Ideally the top of the list would be water instead.

[image]

Any thoughts on how do to this?

---

According to the [GIT HUB DISCUSSION](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3885) this code solves the issue. However I do not know how to integrate it with my code. THanks

```
    void OnClick()
{
  Picker model = Element;
  if (_dialog == null)
  {
    using (var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context))
    {
      builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
      string[] items = model.Items.ToArray();

      builder.SetItems(items, (s, e) => ((IElementController)model).SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, e.Which));

      builder.SetNegativeButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel, (o, args) => { });

      ((IElementController)Element).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);

      _dialog = builder.Create();

      _dialog.SetOnShowListener(AlertDialogListener.Instance);
    }
    _dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    _dialog.DismissEvent += (sender, args) =>
    {
      (Element as IElementController)?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
      _dialog.Dispose();
      _dialog = null;
    };

    _dialog.ListView.Tag = model.SelectedIndex;

    _dialog.Show();
  }
}

…
class AlertDialogListener : Object, IDialogInterfaceOnShowListener
{
  #region Statics

  public static readonly AlertDialogListener Instance = new AlertDialogListener();

  #endregion

  public void OnShow(IDialogInterface dialog)
  {
    var l_dlgAlert = dialog as AlertDialog;

    if (l_dlgAlert.ListView?.Tag == null) return;

    var l_nSelectedIndex = (int)l_dlgAlert.ListView.Tag;

    if (l_nSelectedIndex < 0) return;

    l_dlgAlert.ListView.SetSelection(l_nSelectedIndex);

    int l_nHeight = l_dlgAlert.ListView.MeasuredHeight;

    l_dlgAlert.ListView.SmoothScrollToPositionFromTop(l_nSelectedIndex, (l_nHeight / 2));
  }

}
```

Comment: Create a class the inherits the Picker and add a value for index.  When the class is constructed set index to zero.  If you already have a class then just add an index property.

Comment: Have you tried setting the SelectedItem on the picker?

Comment: @jdweng do you mind expanding a bit on your comment.

Comment: @Andrew I use SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIngredientIndex}". At least in the past I couldn't get selecteditem to work correctly though that was a while ago. Can I not get this behavior with selectedindex?

Comment: The simple solution is to make sure you don't dispose the picker so when you always open the same instance of the picker.  Then you will always be where you left off.  If you do dispose and want to reopen you need a property that keeps track of the index (in the parent) so you can select the old index. If the picker is used for more than one purpose than you need an index for each purpose.

Comment: Each row of the listview shows a picker which is tied to an ingredient through MVVM. I don't specifically dispose of the picker.

Comment: That looks like the default behavior in Android and there is an [discussion](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3885) in Github.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT do you mind showing me how to integrate their solution of modifying  the OnShow Function which they have discribed in your link above. I'll add the code to the question above.

Comment: The code there is modifying the source [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/PickerRenderer.cs#L119). You can try to write a pickerrenderer and override OnClick method, then add new code there.

Comment: I understand in theory what that mean; however, in practice I'm unsure how to proceed. The source there has errors I have no ideal how to resolve as I don't understand what it is doing. I cannot just take the OnClick seciton. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it seems can't override the OnClick event in PickerRenderer. What the code try to do is detect the click event and scroll to/highlight the selected item in the Android pickerRenderer.